# Tips on how to freeze a no-bake cheesecake

Tags: cheesecake

Good day! I have made a no-bake cheesecake in a glass container. Since I could not find the parchment paper, I used a substitute- aluminium foil. Now, the dish has been in the freezer for past two days and still the cake is not firm. On the top, it's a little firm but from the corners, it's runny because of which, I cannot take the cake out of the foil. What should I do to ensure that my cake turns out like a normal cheesecake?

Comment: It will probably be helpful if you tell us more about the recipe, what ingredients and method you used, then we might be able to spot the problem

Comment: And really a freezer? Or do you mean a refrigerator?